# Defining style on a per post basis in Tumblr

Tags: html, css, colors, styling, tumblr

I created the following style to act as a header for blog posts.

```
h4 {font-family: "futura", "helvetica", sans-serif; position:center; line-height:56px;      
font-size:38px; letter-spacing:1px; font-weight:bold; text-align:center; padding-
right:20px; padding-left:20px; color:white;border-style:solid;
border-top-width: 22px; border-bottom-width: 0px; border-left-width:0px; border-right- 
width:0px; border-top-color:#F15B4C; border-bottom-color:#F15B4C; background-
color:#F15B4C;}
```

The site I am working on will feature several "chains" of artwork. Each chain is linked together by artists reworking the same piece of art over time. I want to differentiate each chain with a unique background color for the header.

I'd like to be able to somehow change the color for each post in line, but since this is a hacked Tumblr theme I am limited on how much I can do. Any recommendation on how to create additional styles in Tumblr's mashed up HTML/CSS style?

Comment: For reference, the site I am working on is [Muxel.cc](http://muxel.cc/). And I am new to HTML/CSS so I really appreciate the help! I've tried quite a few possible solutions but no luck so far.

Comment: How will you identify each chain (in the HTML)? That is the key question.

Comment: @Marcin for now I am just defining headline styles in the HTML editor on each post, but I'd love to be able to just use tags on each post and have that define the CSS style it inherits. The only problem there is that each post is actually using two different headline style: one for the larger text and another for the small text beneath it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could possibly do it through tags.

`<div class="caption {block:Tags} {Tag}{/block:Tags}" >`

That should apply the class "chain3" to your classes for that caption.

and then in your CSS...

`.caption.chain3 {background-color:#0000ff;}`

This all depends on your tags being strings that CSS can interpret as class declarations, of course. A tag like "Friendship Is Magic" can't be a CSS class.

Comment: Don't know if this was available when the answer was posted, but the Tumblr template API has `{TagsAsClasses}` now, which will print all tags with HTML class-friendly formatting.